# Neo4j 2.1.x ExecutionEngine number of instances

Tags: java, neo4j

What is the best practice for instances of `ExecutionEngine`? I remember coming across a post on the Neo4j newsgroup saying that one instance should be shared across an app but all examples I can find show suggest otherwise. What is the overall best practice? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly **one**.

Otherwise you duplicate or loose the caches that it keeps with compiled query plans.

You should create it somewhere statically with your `GraphdatabaseService`, or for a server extension have it injected via `@Context CypherExecutor`.

Since Neo4j 2.2. you don't need it anymore, you can finally run Cypher queries directly via `GDB.execute()`

Comment: Perfect. Is `@Context CypherExecutor` documented anywhere? Now that I Google it, I find a few references scattered around but docs aren't popping up.